# How to check file is as per format in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

So i have excel sheet of data which have 20 something columns the customer have requirment that they want to know if any of column is missing from excel im using pandas for converting data into dataframes i used if statements for few columns but as its rigid soulution they want something better
any suggestion ? are there any libraries there?
Thanks

want to check if file have all required columns and display check file if there is some erorr

Answer (score 0):

Here I created a dataframe, but you would be using`df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx`)`

My dataframe has only the three following columns

```py
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Sarah', 'Jack'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Sex':['M', 'M', 'F', 'M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'll make a list then of required cols

```py
REQUIRED_COLUMNS = [
    'Name',
    'Age',
    'Occupation',
    'Sex'
]
# I'll make the columns a set to avoid O^2 looping.
dfColumns = set(df.columns)

for col in REQUIRED_COLUMNS:
    if col not in dfColumns:
        print(f"Column '{col}' is missing.")
```

Et voilà

```bash
>>> Column 'Occupation' is missing.
```

Comment: Thnks for explanation ill get back to you once i applied this @Yasser

Comment: i also have to clear one thing so if requried column is not in data or have some mistake so my code doest work before this i was usign try catch and when i used to get error i just used if statements and put output as check this file any work around this?

Comment: for my solution I don't need the try catch stuff because I am not accessing the columns, ie I am not using df['Occuaption'] to see if it exists, which would have cause an attribute error.
I am simpy checking if a string exists in a set. doesn't cause an error.

Comment: Im telling you if suppose column is missing it will go thru except block i just copied e variable to see what file the error is in